# Why not to extend User in Django REST

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django REST to create users for my app.

Everywhere i look at, for users they extend AbstractBaseUser. 
I tried extending the User model, and it seems to work just fine.

I have an PersonalAbstractUser that extends the Django User. Then, Worker and Client extends PersonalAbstractUser.
Login and custom permissions seem to work just fine up until now, but i am getting concerned when i see that no one else is extending User...

Why is that? Did i miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a question about Django REST, but about Django itself.

The problem with extending the User object directly is that it is already a concrete model, so extending it will use multi-table inheritance. That's not usually a good idea - especially if you're further extending it.

AbstractUser is an abstract model, but (unlike AbatractBaseUser) contains all the fields that User defines. You should use that.

Comment: So, having the user spread across multiple tables is worse than having to write your own user managament(creation, login, etc.)?

Comment: Not sure how your question relates to anything. If you subclass AbstractUser, you don't need to write any custom User management as it is all provided.

Comment: Ok, than i must be doing something wrong, because when i had the model PersonalBaseUser extend the User model, the login worked. But when i changed that to extend AbstractBaseUser, the login does not work anymore.. (added 'username' and USERNAME_FIELD=username)